# Run component method on load vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

hey I'm pretty new to Vue.js and I'm trying to accomplish what seems to be a simple thing but I'm, having trouble. Essentially, I need it so every time a component is loaded into the DOM, one of it's methods fire. Here is my current code, I've tried to use v-on:load but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
Vue.component('graph', {
    props:['graphId','graphData'],
    template: '<canvas v-on:load="{{populateGraph()}}"></canvas>',
    methods: {
        initGraph: function () {
            var settlementBalanceBarChart = new Chart(this.graphId, {
                type: "bar",
                data: settlementBalanceBarData,
                options: settlementBalanceBarOptions
            });
        },
        //this is the function I would like to run
        populateGraph: function () {
            alert('{{graphId}}');
        }
    }

});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    mounted: function(){

    }

});
```

The same code functions fine if I use the v-on:click event

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are [instance lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) that you can use for that. For example:

```
Vue.component('graph', {
    props:['graphId','graphData'],
    template: '<canvas></canvas>',
    created: function () {
        alert('{{graphId}}');
    },
    methods: {}
});
```

Comment: does `created()` run one time after render completed?

Answer (score 5):

You have to call the function prefixed by "this" as following:

```
var data =
{
   cashiers: []
}

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    created: function () {
       this.getCashiers();
    },
    methods: {
         getCashiers: function () {
          vm.cashiers = [];
         }
    }

});
```

Comment: Any reason why you write the `getCashiers` function in the methods declaration and not in the created declaration?

Comment: "methods declarations" is the right place for writing the methods. 

"created declarations" is the place where you can call methods after the component is completely created.

Comment: @kaleidawave Even though in this case it may seem useless, creating it inside methods is a good practice, useful for example when you need to call that same method on creation and on other events.